# mongolab express connection error

Tags: mongodb, express

Getting the following connection error when starting my app:

> [Error: failed to connect to [123:27017]]

My credentials are correct, and I can connect to my db from the shell. I'm using node: 4.4.2, express: 4.13.4, mongoose: 3.8.22, and for the database: mongod 3.0.10. My OS is OSX 10.11.3.

I followed this structure to connect to mongolab

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } }, 
            replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };       
var mongodbUri = 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db';
mongoose.connect(mongodbUri, options);
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: The error says the address `[123:27017]` is not valid. It needs to be either a valid IP address or resolvable hostname. You have clearly obfuscated that part of your actual code, but the general suggestion is if you are in fact using "variables" where the hostname is set, then that content is not actually holding the values you "think" it is.

Comment: thats strange, the URI I'm using is the one mongolab gives me on my database page, and I tested that the connection works on my terminal with the same credentials. I also tried passing the connection string directly to no avail.

Comment: The "error" quoted in your question suggests that the actual "host" address being supplied is `123`, which is of course not a valid address. It in fact "looks like" something that was put in as a placeholder during coding and debugging, but you forgot to change it to the actual host being used. At any rate, since you don't actually tell anyone what you are "actually using" for these values, then it's not really something anyone else can debug for you. The point is go and check it, since what you "think" you are doing is clearly not what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted mongolab support and they found out what was wrong. I had an @ symbol in my password, which needs to be encoded for the connection string. After replacing '@' with '%40' I was able to connect.